# Potential leak of an object stored into CGImageRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Running my code under Xcode Analyze i’ve stumbled into the following block

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithFilter:(CIFilter *)filter
{
    CIContext *ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [ctx createCGImage:filter.outputImage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
}
```

Xcode complains about a potential memory leak:

[image]

What is going on? And how would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 11):

The following looks like a fix, still not sure if this is the best way of handling this over retained reference?

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithFilter:(CIFilter *)filter
{
    CIContext *ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [ctx createCGImage:filter.outputImage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: This is the best way. I can  you :D